# How to Remove "uses" jars form MANIFEST file using gradle?

Tags: java, jar, gradle

I have searched a lot and tried some things but am not able to remove the jars mentioned with the uses keyword under the "Export-Package" field of MANIFEST.MF of a jar. I am using gradle to build my jar.

Currently what is generated.

```
Export-Package: DDS_RMI.engineering;version="8.0.0.0";uses:="DDS,DDS_RMI.engineering.DdsEngineeringService,org.opensplice.DDS_RMI.Impl",DDS_RMI.engineering.DdsEngineeringService;version="8.0.0.0";uses:="DDS,DDS_RMI,org.opensplice.dds.dcps"
```

Desired result

```
Export-Package:DDS_RMI.engineering,DDS_RMI.engineering.DdsEngineeringService
```

Comment: Please describe in detail what you tried (including the relevant code), and what the outcome was. I suppose this is related to OSGi (and Gradle's OSGi plugin?), although you don't mention this.

Comment: I had worked out a workaround by replacing the Export-Package instruction with the use of 'replace instruction' command. However the jars currently are hard coded.
Yes, I am working on an OSGI plugin.